# Is it possible to have more precision in cron?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm receiving some data through a socket in Python2.7 and treating it as I see fit. This data consists mainly of dates and timestamps, that should be then added to crontab as jobs using [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab).

**Problem**: crontab only goes as precise as **minutes**. I need at least **seconds**.

I found this [frequent-cron](https://github.com/homer6/frequent-cron) that seems to do the trick, but since it's "under the MIT license" it's of no use to me. Is there another way to have seconds precision?

Comment: Honest question: what is your problem with the MIT license? It is a very permissive license, even more than GPL. If you need more granular timing, scheduling probably is the wrong tool. Probably this question suffers from the XY problem. The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. This leads to enormous amounts of wasted time and energy, both on the part of people asking for help, and on the part of those providing help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that if I add "14 15 * * * sleep 10s; python myScript.py" in crontab -e it will execute at 15:14:10. Crontab schedules the task to 15:14:00, but I delay the execution by 10 seconds, simulating the second precision I wanted. This might just do the trick, though I wish there was a more elegant way.